# Spring Boot 3: Configure Read Timeout for TestRestTemplate in Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

After migrating from Spring Boot v2 to Spring Boot v3, my integration tests that last longer than 10 seconds time out (before the update, they didn't). I'm using `TestRestTemplate` and tried to `.setReadTimeout` to more than 10 s but it doesn't have an effect. What can I do to enlarge the timeout duration?

Here is my test configuration:

```kotlin
@TestConfiguration
class IntegrationTestConfiguration {
    @LocalServerPort
    private val port = 0

    @Bean
    fun testRestTemplate(): TestRestTemplate {
        val restTemplate = RestTemplateBuilder()
            .rootUri("http://localhost:$port")
            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(50)) // this is not taken into account
        return TestRestTemplate(restTemplate)
    }
}
```

...and my integration test:

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class IntegrationIT {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var rest: TestRestTemplate

    @Test
    fun testSomething() {
        ...
        val response = rest.exchange("/v1/myendpoint", HttpMethod.GET, ..., ...) // this takes longer than 10 s
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response!!.statusCode)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself: I had to add the `@Import` annotation for the test class with the reference to the class that contains my bean.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation::class)
@Import(IntegrationTestConfiguration::class) // I had to add this line
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class IntegrationIT { ...
```

Also, I had to add `@Lazy` for my test configuration class in order for the port to be read at runtime.

```
@Lazy // for the port to work I had to add this annotation
@TestConfiguration
class IntegrationTestConfiguration {
    @LocalServerPort
    private val port = 0

    ...
```